# make does not rebuild target on header file modification

Tags: header, makefile, rule, rebuild

I have a makefile of this kind:

```
program: \
    a/a.o \
    b/b.o 
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o program \
        a/a.o \
        b/b.o

a.o: \
    a/a.cpp \
    a/a.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c a/a.cpp

b.o: \
    b/b.cpp \
    b/b.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c b/b.cpp
```

So in the directory of the makefile I have two subdirectories a and b 
that contain respectively a.h, a.cpp and b.h, b.cpp.
The problem is that if I modify a .cpp file, issuing a make rebuilds the target program 
but if I modify an .h file make do not rebuilds anything but says

```
make: `program' is up to date.
```

I can't understand why, because the .h files are in the prerequisites line
along with the .cpp files.
Interestingly, if I issue a make on an object file target like

```
$ make a.o
```

instead, the modifications to a/a.h
are detected and the target a/a.o is rebuild.
Where is the problem?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem; the example you've provided works fine for me.  So, your real situation must be different in some substantive way from this example.  You'll need to make your example fail the same way your real situation fails, before we can help.

Comment: Ok I trimmed down the real makefile for brevity. In fact after your comment I have tried and found that this shortened example works fine for me too. So I looked for some substantial difference with the real makefile and the only one that I see is that the files are actually contained in subdirectories. I've edited the question to update in this sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subdirectories that you added to the question later are causing the problem indeed. The target `program` depends on `a/a.o` and `b/b.o`, but there are no explicit rules to make those to `.o` files -- only the targets `a.o` and `b.o` are present but those are not in the subdirectories.

Therefore, `make` will look for implicit rules to build `a/a.o` and `b/b.o`. That rule does exist, you will see it being found when you run `make -d`. That implicit rule depends on `a/file_a.cpp` only, not on `a/file_a.h`. Therefore, changing `a/file_a.cpp` will make `a/a.o` out of date according to that implicit rule, whereas `a/file_a.h` will not.

For your reference, the make User's Manual has a section [Catalogue of Implicit Rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules). That also explains that you can use the argument `--no-builtin-rules` to avoid that implicit behavior. If you use that, you will see that `make` can not find any rules to make `a/a.o` and `b/b.o`.

Finally, running `make a.o` *will* run the recipe for the target `a.o` as defined in your makefile. That target does have `a/a.h` as its prerequisite so any change to that file will result in a recompile. But essentially, that has nothing to do with the target `program`, which has different prerequisites.

Comment: Great answer. It put me on the right track. With a bit of work 
I found that to get the desired behaviour, I had to write the target names as the "full path" of the object files (not a.o but a/a.o) and above all to add to the recipe `-o a/a.o` to build
the object files within the directories. Don't know if it's the most elegant way but it now works as desired